# Is AWS Glue Connection a Single Point of Failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, availability-zone

To create a Glue Connection Resource we can just pick one AZ/Subnet form the account VPC. Does it mean if that AZ goes down the Glue jobs that using that connection will fail? If yes how we can make it multi AZs to avoid a single point of failure?

Answer (score 7):

There is no option to switch a subnet at runtime. The Elastic network interfaces with a glue prefix as seen in CloudTrail, show that they are attached to a specific subnet, VPC and security group. These match the connection metadata that you would have added in Glue. If a job fails due to the unlikely event of a complete AZ going down, then you can edit the connection and switch to another subnet. Maybe the folks at AWS support could take a feature request to enhance the product in future.